# Create multiple connections in a single browser window with wcf in silverlight

Tags: wcf, silverlight

I have develop a silverlight 3 chat application in which one user chat with multiple users on a same time.

> In my application a chat window is a
>   silverlight control and a user can
>   open more than 10 chat windows on same
>   time in a single browse window.means
>   every chat window make connection with
>   wcf.

I have allready increase connection limits of wcf using throttlingservice behavior. It works for multile clinets means multiple browses open on same time on different machines and its more than 10. its ok. but if when one user chat with more than 10 users on same time  then on 11th connection its break.

**please help me and provide me solution for this problem.**

Thanks

Comment: What is the error message you get? Andwhen exactly does it occur?

Comment: the error message is communication exception

Comment: Is that the only message you get? No error message text?

Comment: this error show only if i run the project in debug mode.only this message.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something wrong with your client implementation. Do your clients keep the connection to your server open for too long? Ideally you should only have very compact and short request/reply messages between the client and server such that each connection is only short-lived.

A user cannot send messages from each client simultaneously, I suspect. So you should hardly ever have to open more than one connection between client and server simultaneously.

Comment: But all chat windows open in loop and if chat window less than 10 it all chat windows open fine but if go on more than 10 then on 11th it give me communication exception.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get the exception if all the other channels are closed?  There may be a limit to the number of active connections.  You may have to dole out connections between windows when there are more than ten open windows to ensure that you don't attempt to open that 11th connection.